# Real size of iOS 9?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to clear some things. I have an iphone 6s (16 GB). In the **Storage** section I have **used**: 5 GB and **Available**: 6.6 GB.
The difference from 11.6 GB to 16GB I asume it's the OS space.
Why if I add the size of the storage apps from doesn't add up to 5 GB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take into account all other files which get cached in apps, I was trying to work out why I had near to no storage left on my iPhone 6. I noticed that Spotify was taking up a lot of my space as I saved a large playlist offline, I deleted the App and it was still taking up the space. The storage on the device can be taken up my media in iMessage and other social apps such as Messenger & WhatsApp.

I go through and just delete a lot of old photos and videos (seems to be where most of my storage gets taken up) but I regret getting the 16GB model ;-;

Hope this was of some help to you!

Comment: Ty for the info sir

Comment: No worries! Glad it could of been to some help